# Scope of string inside lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, scope, func

I have an interesting scenario in which I've built a validation checking system that maintains a series of requirements in the form `List<Tuple<Func<bool>, string>>` where the Func should return true if validation failed and false otherwise. The string is a corresponding rejection description that describes the condition should the test fail.

In more simple tests like the following the validation system is quite simple:

```
validationChecks.Add(Tuple.Create<Func<bool>, string>(() => 
    value1 == requiredValue, "value 1 did not have the required value"));
```

I'm struggling to understand the scope of variables within the lambda for the Func in a more advanced scenario in which the rejection string is calculated in a call to another part of the system. The scenario looks something like this:

```
string rejectionString = null;
validationChecks.Add(Tuple.Create<Func<bool>, string>(() => {
    rejectionString = CallToAnotherMethodThatReturnsString(parameter);
    if (rejectionString != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, rejectionString));
```

EDIT: As observed through testing, when this check fails the rejectionString from the Tuple is still null. I want the rejectionString that was generated by the CallToAnotherMethod to be used instead, is there any way I can do this using ref or otherwise? I need the Func's code to be able to affect the value of the string inside Item2 of the Tuple.

<strike>The problem is that the code inside of `CallToAnotherMethodThatReturnsString` might be code that I only want executed ONCE. However should the check fail I want to use the string that would have been returned from it as my rejection description in the Tuple. I'm unable to tell at this point what the effect of my use of `rejectionString` in this second example will accomplish? Will rejectionString inside the Tuple always be null? Or if `CallToAnotherMethodThatReturnsString` returns a different value will it be updated?</strike>

Comment: What were your observations when you ran the sample code (or variations thereof) in various tests? What did you discover?

Comment: Good point, I hardcoded a string value in place of CallToAnotherMethodThatReturnsString inside the second example and the rejection string from the failed test is null. Which is not at all what I was hoping...

Comment: As you have and would continue to discover, closing over outer variables is tricky, and it's typically not something people have success with when doing things in loops (which your list would lend itself to). I would suggest rethinking your strategy here if you want the message to vary based on a function result. But who knows, perhaps someone will come along with an alternate idea.

Comment: Could it be that this code is inside a method, and 'rejectionString' is dropped as soon as the method is finished? That would also mean the scope from the original rejectionString is gone. Since its a string its copied and you will lose the reference. Try to wrap the string into an object (just a wrapper) with a setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea that might work. I think if you change your second Tuple parameter to a Func that returns string instead of string value, you could come close to what you need.

```
string rejectionString = null;
validationChecks.Add(Tuple.Create<Func<bool>, Func<string>>(() =>
{
     rejectionString = CallToAnotherMethodThatReturnsString(parameter);
     if (rejectionString != null) {
      return true;
     } else {return false;}
 }, 
 ()=>rejectionString));
```

In the first case your validation check would be set as

```
validationChecks.Add(Tuple.Create<Func<bool>, Func<string>>(() => value1 == requiredValue, ()=>"value 1 did not have the required value"));
```

And your validation is logic is then

```
if(validationChecks[0].Item1()==false)
 var error = validationChecks[0].Item2();
```

Comment: Hmmm this is an interesting suggestion, I'll play around with it this afternoon and see if I can get it to do what I need. Thanks for the thoughts! I'll mark as answer if it works out. +1 for now

Comment: Wow thanks! After some testing this seems to be working perfectly. Definitely learning more about how lambdas and captured variables work. You rock

Comment: @JesseCarter Great.. I think your problem was more in that how string works... String is a reference type but is immutable so behaves similar to value types. In your case when you created tuple, tuple got a copy of rejectionString which was null at the time Tuple was created. Later changeing rejectionString did not change the string stored in tuple, you always got null out of Item2 no matter rejectionString variable changed.